# как в mercurial отключить автоматический мерж

Tags: mercurial, hg

Суть проблемы состоит в том что mercurial автоматически применяет изменения, с базовой ветки а не с ветки default, необходимо файлы смержить в ручную, с mercurial ранее не работал но в git сделал бы просто rebase на master.